# How can I find documents which matching field and data perfectly(not same data order)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb4.0

I'm begginer at mongoDB

I want to get documents which matching perfectly in mongoDB. id 1 and id 5 document have same fields(but `"favorite.foods.fastfood"` array not same order).

I mean, I want to get id 1 and 5 but not id 4.

here are documents

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "red",
      "foods": {
        "fruits": "banana",
        "fastfood": [
          "burger",
          "sandwich"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "green",
      "foods": {
        "noodles": "ramen",
        "fastfood": [
          "fries",
          "burger",
          "corn dog"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "red",
      "foods": {
        "soup": "cream soup"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "red",
      "foods": {
        "fruits": "banana",
        "fastfood": [
          "sandwich",
          "burger"
        ],
        "soup": "cream soup"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "red",
      "foods": {
        "fruits": "banana",
        "fastfood": [
          "sandwich",
          "burger"
        ],
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I tried to this query, but failed.

Please help me.

```
db.collection.find({
  "favorite.foods.fruits": "banana",
  "favorite.foods.fastfood": {
    "$all": [
      "sandwich",
      "burger"
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: First of all, I think you need to provide reason/motive why query id: 1 & 5 only. In my opinion, if you want to get `fastfood` array in sequence, then it will query documents: id 4 & 5. Unless there is a special characteristic in documents: id 1 & 5, then you can query with it. Maybe add a condition with [`_id: { $ne: 4 }`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OjyjlxsDqKH) but sound doesn't make sense to define the query condition based on id (identifier).

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by *matching perfectly* ? document 1 and 5 are having different permutation of `fastfood` array so canonically *matching perfectly* can only fit one of them.

Comment: @YongShun I try to make searching tool with  ```favorite.foods``` in all data. so, I think id doesn't need in this case.

Comment: @ray I make searching tool. 'matching perfectly' means only same data without permutation of array. I want to get all documents that ```favorite.foods.fruits``` is "banana" and ```favorite.foods.fastfood``` is "sandwich" and "burger".

Comment: and don't want document that have other fields like ```favorite.foods.soup```

Comment: Think this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gzqu5o9BD2G) match your requirement. Add condition `"favorite.foods.soup": { "$exists": false }` which mean the field doesn't existed.

Comment: I think @YongShun made a great note. @bob you really need to think about your purpose / intention. From what we have now, you are basically defeating the greatest advantage of MongoDB's flexibility on the dynamic schema, which is highly counter-intuitive. YongShun's answer can meet your requirement for now, but when you are having more than the `soup` field, you will end up having a nearly hard-coded query of excluding all other fields.

Comment: @ray yeah....that's the problem. I thought some query that can count fields in mongoDB..